# Tuscany JAXWS SCA issue

Tags: jax-ws, soa, sca, apache-tuscany

I am making two simulatenous calls from one component to second component using JAX WS and I am having issues, this is what happens
Take two component, component A, component B and Request 1 and Request 2

1. Request 1 calls from Component A to Component B and component B , some database queries are running
2. Request 2 calls some methods and Compoenet and tries to access Component B, for some reason there is only instance to access Component B and since this instance is used by Request 1, Request 2 doesnt get access and surprsingly Request 2 never tries again
3. Request 1 finishes calls with Component B and calls some methods on Component A and tries to access Component and never gets access to Component B

Both request hangs

Following are the logs

```
18:42:44,183 INFO  [xxx.OrderProcessServiceImpl] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-3) In checkCustomer: before getCard 65
18:42:44,185 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-4) Hibernate: select xxx
18:42:44,188 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-4) Hibernate: select xxx
18:42:44,208 INFO  [xxx.OrderProcessServiceImpl] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) IN checkCustomer : AFTER 
18:42:44,216 INFO  xxx.OrderProcessServiceImpl] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) BEFORE CPI 3092
```

Comment: We improved your post so it becomes readable. Please check what is done and read more about [formatting here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: how to add connections to pool if tuscany/axis 2 /sca architecture is implemeneted..can anyone help on this?